# Privileges screen is just off enough to be annoying

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Clearly the container is messed up.
Can we fix it? Or is this some that should be taken up to the big boys in meta SO?

Comment: Please mention your specific browser and operating system when reporting such bugs. I can confirm I have the same problem on firefox 21.0 and chrome 25.0.1364.152 running on 64bit Linux.

Comment: @terdon this is a 64 bit win 7 machine. I tried it with IE 10.0.9200.16660 and firefox 23.0.1 on a similar machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be with you in the next build (rev 2013.9.20.1028).

Comment: good stuff, looking forward to it